# DICOM Image/Videos on Mobile

Tags: jquery, html, mobile, streaming, dicom

I have a final year project to develop a Mobile application that is able to view DICOM images and videos. The videos would be needed to be transferred using dynamic adaptive streaming over http.

I looked to developing the app using iOS but i had a issues importing DCMTK/ITK onto xCode as most guides were outdate.

I started looking at developing the application using HTML5/jQuery and Phonegap to deliver it cross platform.

My questions is how to take the approach in developing such app? I have not had much programming experience and have difficulty in finding an approach to this. I would like to store and retrieve the DICOM images/videos from DropBox or just somewhere in a server. I am not looking to have them for PACS server unless thats the only option as i do not have access to one.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to display DICOM images in HTML5, you need to either:

1. convert them to JPEG or another web-compatible image format
2. write a DICOM parser in javascript w/ various image compression codecs to read raw DICOM and convert it into a format viewable on the web (say, for example, into 8 bit pixel values to insert into a canvas element)

the first one is much easier than the second. Let's say that's what you want to do. You will need a server that when asked for an image, would take the corresponding DICOM image and convert it into a JPEG, and then serve it to your client application, which will then display it.

You can use the WADO protocol and an open source PACS system (something like [dcm4chee](http://www.dcm4che.org/)) to get JPEG versions of your DICOM files. WADO is a protocol used to provide Web Access to DICOM Objects, so all you have to do is request the right file, and the WADO-compatible server will be able to get you the JPEG you want.

There are then a lot of details to worry about, but, this should be enough to get you started.

Comment: THank you very much for the response Anatoly. I have managed to run dcm4chee system with WADO and I have send some images to the system which i can view them via the dcm4chee web. I have to been trying to find out how i would implement this on my client - my guess is to a PHP server side which queries dcm4chee DB for patient details return it with JSON and then i can get study/series/object to parse into the WADO request? OR are there any other simplier methods, or existing solutions that i can just implement as i am not required to build this from scratch? thank you again.

Comment: @mario91tr glad it helps! I would first see if you could find already-existing dcm4chee web services that give this info, even if that info is in XML. then, you can use an XSLT to transform from XML to JSON. If you don't want to go that route, look through the DCM4chee codebase to see the SQL queries that they use to retrieve this info, and then build a simple PHP service to do same. I would go w/ DCM4CHEE first, as it would be the least effort, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

My answer probably comes too late but, in your case, you could give a try to [Orthanc](http://www.orthanc-server.com/). Orthanc is a lightweight, open-source DICOM server that comes with a RESTful API. Thus, you can interact with the stored DICOM images through standard AJAX calls, without using any DICOM toolkit.